# How to update node value to a value provided by user in nested JSON structure, provided that key value is unique for that node and is provided?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, indexing

JSON Data below with every nested node is having unique key name.
How can we update templateData - value of hide whose key is "def".
Manual Way is - index = this.fields[0].templateData[0].fieldGroup[0].templateData[0].hide = false.

But if JSOn grows like this then how can value of hide can be updated if we provide JSON Node key value.

```js
fields = [
  {
    key: 'abc',
    templateData: [
      {
        hide: false,
        fieldGroup: [
          {
            key: 'def',
            templateData: [
              {
                hide: true
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'tyu',
    templateData: [
      {
        hide: true
      }

    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:javascript] but also [tag:json.net].  Json.NET [is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json.net/info)  Are you actually asking how to do this using Json.NET in [tag:.Net] or should the Json.NET tag be removed?

Comment: This is in Javascrippt/anlgular where we need to retrieve key value. You can ignore json.net and indexing

Comment: Considering you're talking about updating the data, and you have an equals sign and no quoted key names, I'm guessing you're not actually talking about JSON; just data which may have been pulled from JSON at some point in the past.

Comment: Also, `templateData` is an array; what happens if there are multiple objects in the array that have a `hide` property?